# Is this a good way to avoid null return?

Tags: java, exception, null

I'm currently working on a simple method which converts the content of a file to a string. I saw several topics covering some detail about this question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements)). However I can use the try catch or a return do_nothing as mentioned in the previous linked answer. The code:

```
public static String getStringFromFile(String path) throws EmptyFileException {
    String data =null; 

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            data += line +"\n";
        }
        if (data == null) {
            throw new EmptyFileException();
        }

    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            showExceptionMessage("File not found");
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {
        showExceptionMessage("Can't read the file");
    }

    return(data);

}

private static void showExceptionMessage(String message) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

So what would be "better" throwing an exception if the file is empty or just using return doNothing() (were doNothing is the function that does nothing, makes sense right? hahah).

Comment: From an application point of view, is it OK to handle a missing file, empty file and bad read as a general "no message found" situation that results in a "do nothing" flow? Or put another way, do you only want to show a message if it was found in the file, otherwise show nothing (even if there was an error typing to get the message from the file)?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a good way to avoid null return?

Yes, always return "existing" object instead of null if you can. Null Object Pattern is a good aproach to avoid that.

> So what would be "better" throwing an exception if the file is empty
>   or just using return doNothing()

In your case throwing an exception is overkill for me. You should throw an exception when you don't expect particular behaviour. Have a look at FileNotFoundException. You always expect that file exists so it's a good choice to throw exception when you can't find this file.

So as metioned above null is bad, so why can't you return empty string? :) In this case it will work like Null Object Pattern, like placeholder :)

Comment: I was thinking it would be strange to return an empty string because the user/programmer would expect the file to contain at least something (otherwise it would be useless to convert the data to a string)?